# BigQuery resources exceeded error

Tags: python, google-bigquery, parquet

I have a Bigquery table of the following format:
"Device", "t", "BedOccupancy", and "Raw".
The table consists of ~300,000 lines and is intended for millions in the future.

See example here:
[image]

Each line in the table corresponds to a second of a bed-mounted sensor measurements. The field "Raw" contains the sensor data which are 1000 integers encoded as comma-separated values in one long string.

When I query the table for selecting fields other than "Raw", results are good, for example:

```
SELECT
  Device, t
FROM
  [table:table1.RawData]
WHERE
  BedOccupancy == 1
ORDER BY
  t
```

But when I also SELECT "Raw" field, I get the following error:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory..

Any ideas how to tackle this?

UPDATE #1:

Also without the "order by t", when I SELECT all four fields, I get the following error:

> Response too large to return

It seems the "Raw" field is doing a hard time for BigQuery. Is there a more efficient way of storing these 1000 values per each line? I don't need to query them, just keep the whole chunk of values per each line.

Comment: Your order by is not infinity scalable that's why you get the error. Are you sure you need that order by there?

Comment: Yes, I'm building a database of sensor measurements and I need be able to fetch sensor data ordered by time. Is there a workaround for this? Maybe a way to make BigQuery store the data by time index as default?

Comment: I think that what you are trying to do hear is to look over *all of your data. Which is not quite natural, that's why it fails. Try doing a query which doesn't read all data. Add limit, aggregations to reach a "human" can understand data set. As with this you are fetching into your browser all the "MOON" and it crashes normally.

Comment: I indeed want to keep all the data in the table and fetch large parts of it. Isn't it possible?

Comment: It's possible but you need to script it so extract it as large output in BigQuery UI is not possible. Your browser cannot handle.

Comment: simply switch to using BigQuery Standard SQL - `SELECT Device, t, Raw FROM \`project.dataset.RawData\` WHERE BedOccupancy = 1`

Comment: Thanks, still I get an error: _"Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. ORDER BY operator used too much memory.."_

Comment: As @Pentium10 mentioned, order by won't scale if your result size is too large. 

If you do need ordered output, make the output as narrow as possible (as few columns as possible) and restrict the number of rows (maybe do it for a month instead of all time, or whatever).

If you're using ORDER BY just so you can see the top / bottom of some distribution, consider the various "approximate top N" functions:
http://g3doc/storage/googlesql/g3doc/approximate_aggregate_functions

Comment: As I said, I do need the data ordered by time as it is sensor measurements (time series). In addition, see in the "update #1" section of my post, also when not ordering I get an error _"Response too large to return"_. This is frustrating as I thought BigQuery to be much more powerful! Are they any other databases which can handle this?

Comment: @Pentium10, Mikhail and Y Y,  is there any chance you can post an answer with a better explanation of what you have commented here please? Thank you.